# How to obtain a German work permit for a software engineer without educational background

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany

I'm a web developer at an intermediate level (some experience but not senior) and I'm about to receive a job offer from an employer in Berlin.

For this purpose, I would require a work permit. However, I do not have any university degree or any training certificate as I've learned the skills necessary by myself, which is fairly common in this profession.

I understand that the Blue Card is not for me so I won't be asking about it. However, the employer and I would like to get a sense of the process and whether I could get the work permit based only on my skills and a contract, without any education certificates.

Is this possible? If so, what's the procedure for both employee and employer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following a little research I found the answer specific to my condition:
A citizen of any of these countries:

> United States of America, Australia, Canada, Israel, Japan, New Zealand, Switzerland, the Republic of Korea

Can basically apply without any requirements for a certificate.

The process is the following:

Upon receiving a binding job offer & contract, the employer has to send the contract, along with 2 documents and (preferably) a copy of the candidate's CV:

> Die benötigten Formulare für die Vorabprüfung finden Sie unter
>   folgendem [Link](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/web/content/DE/Formulare/Detail/index.htm?dfContentId=L6019022DSTBAI516421).
>
> Die Standortübersicht mit den Kontaktdaten finden Sie unter folgendem
>   [Link](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/web/content/DE/BuergerinnenUndBuerger/ArbeitundBeruf/ArbeitsJobsuche/ArbeitinDeutschland/Arbeitsmarktzulassung/Detail/index.htm?dfContentId=L6019022DSTBAI531395).

to the *Bundesagentur für arbeit*. The contract will be examined and the agency will have around 2 weeks to look for a suitable candidate who has an EU citizenship.

If they fail to find one, the contract will be approved and the candidate will be able to proceed to obtain a residence permit for the purpose of taking up employment.

The major difference between citizens from the countries listed above to any other, non EU citizens, are these two:

- The citizens from these countries (as listed) are not required to introduce any vocational training certificate
- They are allowed to enter Germany before the process is complete (and before it is started) and start/continue it there.

*The information above has been received from *Bundesamt für Migration und Flüchtlinge* and is available from their hotline:

> The hotline is available from 9:00 a.m. to 3:00 p.m. CET, Monday through Friday, and the telephone number +49 30 1815-1111.

Documents explaining in German were received by email from the *Bundesamt für Migration und Flüchtlinge*

Comment: Hi @RanST - I believe for a Software Engineer they don't actually need any check if an European can take up the job, because it is a a whitelist.

Did you get the approval? How long did it take?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the bigger problem might be to find an employer (not someone who awards you a freelance contract!) which will give you a binding job offer while being willing to wait an unpredictable amount of time (for sure some months) for an approval. What I am trying to say is: For pretty much generic software engineering topics, there is no shortage in supply of EU citizens which can get hired without the bureaucracy it takes to hire a non-EU citizen. Therefore the employer will need a good reason to go down that road.

Answer (score 4):

> [Germany requires skilled workers in a number of industries](http://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/for-qualified-professionals/visa/quick-check). As a result, in the summer of 2013 a number of policies were introduced to make it easier for non-EU citizens with non-academic vocational qualifications to work in Germany. Since then, you have been able to take up employment if you meet the following criteria:
>
> A whitelist of such professions is [available here](https://www3.arbeitsagentur.de/web/wcm/idc/groups/public/documents/webdatei/mdaw/mtm5/~edisp/l6019022dstbai777367.pdf?_ba.sid=L6019022DSTBAI777372).
>
> You have received a binding job offer. A list of vacancies is [available here](http://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/for-qualified-professionals/working/job-listings).
>
> Your qualification has been recognised as being equivalent to a German qualification. Further information on the recognition of vocational credentials is [available here](http://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/for-qualified-professionals/working/job-listings). You will have to apply to have your qualifications recognised while you’re still in your home country.
>
> If the assessment authority decides that you require practical experience in order to obtain full recognition (e.g. practical work as part of an adaptation period), you can apply for a limited residence permit for this purpose.

Comment: @HelloWorldGuy good, I see you asked a separate question, as you needed to; delete your comment (and I'll delete mine) to keep things clean. Hopefully, you'll get the answer directly to your question (which I don't have :-)